# App crashes on iPod

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, ios6, xcode4.3

I have created one application for iPhone. Application does a search for all watersports around the world. It is webservice based application.

My application runs smooth on Simulator without any crash report but when I create ipa file and launch same application on my iPod (I dont have my own iPhone) the application crashes after some time. Scenario of crash is not fixed so I assume this is because of Memory Leak or memory warning.

I used this function `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to identify memory warning but the function doesn't get called on simulator.

My Xcode version is 4.3 and unfortunately I updated the version of my iPod to iOS 6.0 so I can not test the app by connecting my iPod to the Mac. I am going to update my Mac and Xcode very soon but not soon enough to make this issue resolve/test.

Any ideas?

Comment: App does not crash on simulator so I can not generate crash log. App crashes on device only and because I updated my device version I can not connect device to my xcode which is of older version 4.3.

Comment: Check [how-to-find-crash-logs](http://www.ondemandworld.com/how-to-find-crash-logs/) or [get-crash-reports-logs-from-iphone-ipad](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/07/get-crash-reports-logs-from-iphone-ipad/)

Comment: ohh. I did not know about this. Thank you very much. Now I can at least find out the cause of error. Thanks again. Checking the links now.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Adding as an answer with some more details. Once you get the error message, you should be able to fix it.

Comment: yes ofcourse. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the crash log from device using the following approaches. Check [how-to-find-crash-logs](http://www.ondemandworld.com/how-to-find-crash-logs/) or [get-crash-reports-logs-from-iphone-ipad](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/07/get-crash-reports-logs-from-iphone-ipad/). You can symbolicate the crash log to find out the root cause. Check this question here for more details on that part [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports). Once you got the issue, you should be able to fix it.

Comment: If you want, you can vote-up on multiple answers. There is an up arrow above the number 0 in both answers. If you press on that, that will do a vote-up on the answers. Only one answer can be marked with tick mark, but vote-up can be done on any answer you see in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, put a temporary label then modify it when the `didRecieveMemoryWarning` is called or make an alert view that pops up when `didRecieveMemoryWarning` is called.

Also, run with Instruments app, its a great way to monitor your memory usage and identify memory leaks. Also try Product -> Analyze to find memory leaks from in-Xcode. Instruments is part of the SDK just search for it in spotlight.

Comment: I used all three ways you have mentioned. Instead of label I put uialertview in my didRecieveMemoryWarning, also Product -> Analyze and also instruments. But everything is fine.